# in Magento 2,How can I implement star rating in my custom module

Tags: magento2, ratings

I am Unable to move ahead in implementing the star rating in magento 2,because i was clue less,Please can anyone give me possible solutions,so that i can complete my star rating.

Comment: Where are you doing this? a Bit more info, on what you have done would be helpful?

Comment: I was Trying to implement from my custom module template page. @NathanielR